# Haskell: A game of darts

Tags: list, function, haskell

I am trying to implement a game of darts in haskell. I chose to represent the result of every leg in different layers of lists. Every first element of the inner list represents the multiplier (single, double, triple), every second element represents the value of points which are getting multiplied. Every player starts with a score of 501 points. These points are getting reduced by the amount of points a player shots in every turn. If a player reaches 0 points he will win the full leg.

This is an example for an random leg in which the starting player wins:

```
          leg1 = [[[3,20],[3,20],[3,20]],[[3,20],[3,19],[2,25]],[[3,19], 
          [3,19],[3,19]],[[3,20],[3,19],[2,25]],[[2,25],[2,25],[2,25]]] 
          -- the outer list represents the full leg.
          -- the second layer of lists represents a full turn of a player. 
          -- the inner lists are composed of a pair of two elements
          -- and every pair represents one shot.
```

My goal is to write a function which takes a random leg as input parameter and do the following for different chases:

Chase 1: It should return 1 if the starting player wins the full leg.

Chase 2: It should return 2 if the other player wins.

Chase 3: It should return 0 if there is a invalid combination of the inner
         pair of list elements (for example [3,0] is invalid because triple 0 
         does not exist in the game).

Example:

```
      legWinner leg1 -- call of the function with parameter.
     -> 1            -- return value.
```

I am not quite sure how to approach the definition of this function.

Comment: You can try to first implement the cases individually, or if that is still too hard, start with simpler problems.

Comment: Why do you allow invalid things to be expressible? The second layer is three shots, the inner layer is two numbers. I would define `data Multiplier = Single | Double | Triple`, `type Shot = (Int, Multiplier)`, `type Turn = (Shot, Shot, Shot)`, `type Leg = [(Turn, Turn)]`, and things would be cleaner to deal with. You can write `shotPoints :: Shot -> Int`, then `turnPoints :: Turn -> Int` in terms of `shotPoints`, etc.